# Unable to open file

Tags: php

I installed php manual and tried to open it, but:

> Warning: fopen(e.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Comment: check the file permission.

Answer (score 1):

Are you opening this in PHP? Is it on a server? If so you need to set the permissions of the folder it is in to allow reading the file. If it's just in a folder on your computer, is it then protected by any restrictions in the folder settings?

Answer (score 0):

As Joshua 'Cuppers' Whittle answer the problem is most likely with your CHMOD permissions. However, I will post my answer in the more PHP and "dynamic" form.

Before opening the file:

```
if (substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('e.txt')), -4) == 1777) {
    chmod('e.txt', 777)
}
// And now the fopen(); part of your code
```

*(Sadly, I cant test it myself, so this answer is theoretical only.)*